# Turning off Notifications MonoTouch

Tags: c#, ipad, xamarin.ios, apple-push-notifications

I have created an iPhone app in MonoTouch. The app is a test where the test taker should not get interrupted during the test. How do you make sure that notifications are turned off while my app is running so the test taker will not be interrupted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry, this is not possible.  MonoTouch does not give any more access to the OS than Cocoa and this is not possible in Cocoa.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10026471/1370166) for more details.